# Replace the div elements after ajax call instead of appending to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a *div* element inside my php script, `<div id="abc"></div>` however it contains some other *div* elements as well.What this div element look like is

```
<div id="abc">
    <div>
        //some content
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using jquery ajax to `.append()` some returned html content inside the `abc div` but what it does is that it simply *appends* the response html content to the `abc div`. Obviously the name says so ,what i wanna know it that is there any function like which replaces all the content inside, by the returned content instead of appending to it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `html()` instead of `append()`.

```
$('#abc').html(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

If i got you right

```
$('#abc').html(result);
```

should do the trick. It will just replace the content of your abc-div.

Comment: auwgh ... too slow ;)